Anomaly in boiling point as compared to melting point in d-block
Consider the following graph:-

In the above graph, it can be observed that the melting point of Chromium is higher than that of Vanadium (though there's not much greater difference despite the fact that chromium has 6 unpaired electrons while vanadium has only 3; I would assume it's because half filled d orbital stability of chromium that it's unwilling to delocalise electrons over metallic lattice ; correct me in the answer if I am incorrect).
Now consider another graph:-

It is observed that the boiling point of chromium is abruptly low in comparison to vanadium and even other 3d series elements that arrive before it (Sc and Ti). Why is it that the once not so difference in melting point of Chromium and Vanadium changed drastically when we consider there boiling points???
Note:- (1) I know that in some graphs and experimental data, it is given that V has higher melting point than Cr. I would assume that it's correct but the fact that there isn't much difference between there melting points still persists.
(2) I am a high school student so kinda keep the language of explanation simple (though you may go into details).
